# Help with function substitution problem!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**Question:**

> If $f(x) = x^3-(a+b)x^2  + abx$, find the value of $f(a)$ and explain the significance of $(x – a)$.

Im doing a grade $12$ advanced functions course online at the moment and this is one that I am confused by. I substituted the $a$ value for $x$ in the equation and am not sure if that is right. Also I have no idea what the $x - a$ part of the question is talking about.

If someone could help me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$f(a) = a^3 -(a+b)a^2 + aba = a^3 - a^3+ ba^2 - b a ^2 = 0$$

then $a$ is a zero of the polynomial. Thus  $x - a$ is a factor of $f(x)$, that is, $$f(x) = (x - a)g(x)$$

with $\partial g(x) = 2$.

Comment: In case you need any more details don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(a)=a^3-(a+b)a^2+aba=a^3-a^3-a^2b+a^2b=0$$
Therefore:
$$f(x)=(x-a)p(x)$$
with p(x) being a polynomial of degree 2.